# Problem passing words through my function

Tags: c

I have writen this code but for some reason i cannoy find where it is going wrong. There are no syntax errors in it but whenever i input a word it tells me it is a palindrome even when it is not. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int palindrome()
{
    int i = 0, n = 1, len = 0;
    char word[100], reverse[100];

    for (i; word[i] != '\0'; i = i + 1)
    {
        len++;
    }

    for (i = len - 1; 0 <= i; i = i - 1)
    {
        reverse[len - i - 1] = word[i];
    }

   for (i = 0; i < len; i = i + 1)
   {
      if (reverse[i] != word[i])
        return 0;
      else
        return 1;
   }

 }
```

Comment: Your function has no parameters. `word` is a local variable totally unrelated to the arugment you try to pass i nyour main function.

Comment: Oh yes i see that now, how would i fix this to work then do you know? @Alexander

Comment: Add a `char word[100]` parameter to the function signature of `palindrome`: `int palindrome(char word[100]) { ... }`, and remove the local variable.

Comment: What happens when your input exceeds 100 characters in length?  Use `scanf("%99s", word);`

Comment: Think of it like plugs and sockets. In `main` you have a call to the `palindrome` function. You try to pass an local variable called `word` as an argument. Arguments are like a plug, parameters are like sockets. You're trying to plug `word` into a socket (parameter) of the `palindrome` function, but it has none.

Comment: @Alexander Ty that really helped me actually undrstand it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues going on here.

The first issue is your `palindrome` function has no parameter. In your `main` function you're reading the users input into a buffer called `word`, but you aren't passing that buffer to the `palindrome` function. You need to pass it so the function can access it. You appear to be redeclaring `word` in `palindrome`, but this is a new buffer and is not the same as the buffer declared in `main`.

```c
int palindrome(const char *word)
```

The second issue is partially stylistic, partially optimization: You are creating a new buffer called `reverse` which is intended to hold the reversed contents of the `word` buffer. You are then intending to compare the `reverse` buffer with the `word` buffer. A simpler way to do this would be to index the `word` buffer backwards. You can do this in one loop:

```c
for (i = 0; i < len; i = i + 1)
{
    if (word[i] != word[len - 1 - i])
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The third issue is you're returning `0` when they aren't a palindrome and `1` when they are. The problem is your logic in `main` is checking `0` to determine if they *are* a palindrome which is the reverse of what you want.

The complete solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int palindrome(const char *word)
{
    int i;
    const int len = strlen(word);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i = i + 1)
    {
        if (word[i] != word[len - 1 - i])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char word[100];

    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", word);

    if (palindrome(word) == 1)
      printf("This string is a palindrome.\n");
    else
      printf("This string is not a palindrome.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop always returns after the first iteration.

Comment: @Alexander Good catch, I've corrected it.

Comment: I would also convert to use `bool` while you're at it.

Comment: @Alexander `bool` exists in C99, but not C89/90. The poster didn't mention which version of C they're using, but since they're declaring variables at the top of their functions, they might be using C89.

Comment: This will sound snarky/snide, but it's a genuine question: Is 31 year backwards comparability something C programmers usually concern themselves with? Particularly when doing something as learning a palindrome function as a new programmer?

Comment: No snark taken. I just didn't want to post code that might fail for them. If I knew for sure they're targeting a newer version of C I would have used bool and declared the looper counter `i` in the loop itself.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the `palindrome` function has no parameters. I suspect this is the primary cause.

However, there are several other smaller issues, which a more succinct style could help avoid. Most pertinent, in the third `for` loop of the `palindrome` function, the function will always return after the first iteration. (If the first character in `reverse` and `word` do not match, `return 0`, otherwise function will `return 1` and no further iterations are run.